# String as a GeoCoordinate

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing an application which is storing places in database.

The problem is:

I have a main view of map, then I click add place button. The button goes to standard form which contains name, description and coordinates. Coordinates I am taking from map and changing to string. Then it saves in SQLite database.

But I have no idea how use geocoordinates from DB, because they are strings, not a GeoCoordinates, and simply I can't use them to for example pushpin with binding data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering there is no `GeoCoordinate.Parse()` method and assuming your string representation comes from `GeoCoordinate.ToString()`, you could use something like this:

```
public GeoCoordinate ParseGeoCoordinate(string input)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("input");
    }

    if (input == "Unknown")
    {
        return GeoCoordinate.Unknown;
    }

    // GeoCoordinate.ToString() uses InvariantCulture, so the doubles will use '.'
    // for decimal placement, even in european environments
    string[] parts = input.Split(',');

    if (parts.Length != 2)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid format");
    }

    double latitude = Double.Parse(parts[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    double longitude = Double.Parse(parts[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    return new GeoCoordinate(latitude, longitude);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand idea of function but I am very beginner so maybe you can explain me few things: first is how to take input data (on my page i have it as string in textBlock. How to take if from there? And how to call final result of function? That's my main doubts

Comment: Your question said that you needed to persist it to the db. Regardless, you can use the code like so: `GeoCoordinate coordinate = `GeoCoordinateUtility.ParseGeoCoordinate(textBlock1.Text);`

Comment: hello again. another problem is that in line (input.Split(", ");) I see an error that he cannot convert from string to char and that 'The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments' can you help me with this?

Comment: how to do the same in case of multiple records? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347709/multiple-pushpins-based-od-db-data